# Can't increment integer in Cocos2d-x V 3.0

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to increment an integer.I have this code here :

Utils.h :

```
class Utils{
static HUD* hudLayer();
static Layer* layerWithTag(int tag);
};
```

Utils.cpp :

```
HUD* Utils::hudLayer(){
    return (HUD*)Utils::layerWithTag(TAG_HUD);
}
Layer* Utils::layerWithTag(int tag)
{
    Scene *sc = Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene();
    if (sc->getTag() == TAG_GAME_SCENE) {
        Layer *layer = (Layer *)sc->getChildByTag(tag);
        return layer;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

HUD.h

```
class HUD : public Layer{

public:
    int score1;
    Label* scoreLabel1;
    virtual bool init();
    void didScore();
    CREATE_FUNC(HUD);
};
```

HUD.cpp :

```
bool HUD::init(){
    if(!Layer::init()){return false;}
    score1 = 0;


    scoreLabel1 = Label::createWithSystemFont(CCString::createWithFormat("Score : %d",score1)->getCString(), “Arial“, 64);
    scoreLabel1->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.0f, 1.0f));
    scoreLabel1->setPosition(Point(20, Utils::s().height-10));
    this->addChild(scoreLabel1);
    return true;
}
void HUD::didScore(){
    score1+=10; // Error HERE after coming from onTouchBegan (says parentis null)
    scoreLabel1->setString(CCString::createWithFormat("Score : %d",score1)->getCString());
}
```

In GameScene.h now i have this in onTouchBegan method :

```
bool GameScene::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *unused_event)
{
    Point location = touch->getLocationInView();
    location = Director::getInstance()->convertToGL(location);

    if(location.x < 300.0f){
        Utils::hudLayer()->didScore();
    }
    return true;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here ?
I can increment an integer in V 2.x the same way but not in V 3.0 . WHY ?

Comment: There is so much wrong here, I cant begin to explain. Your coding style is, umm, interesting. A lot has changed in v3. You are probably getting an error in `didScore()`. I'd say by quick look that this is a scope issue with `score1` and `onTouchBegan`

Comment: like what is wrong with my code ..??

Comment: look at the answer below. This is all about the scope of `score1`. You have a misunderstanding of event listeners, I think. Just because something answers to an even doesn't mean the event automatically knows about the objects and variables of what called it.

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x v3 is a new listener system for events (touches, accelerometr etc.), you need to create listener for getting touches. In GameScene::init you should put something like that

```
auto listener1 = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener1->setSwallowTouches(true);
listener1->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchBegan, this);

this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener1, this);
```

Look at:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/EventDispatcher_Mechanism

Comment: so you are saying i entered in the onTOuchBegan method without following whats written in your above post ?
I already had done this part thats why i was able to enter onTouchBegan method !!!